movie has two storyline for woman at russia and france
I'm looking for a musical-mystery-drama movie , released at 90s i think
Language: many languages such as French , Russian
Country: Russia , France
details : the film talking about two stories for a woman has an Angelic voice which has two lives so 

the first story taking place in russia at soviet's last years , she was sang in Coral , On the way to home, she saw a demonstration and saw her Similarity in life which was on the bus . Then she waited for her lover and went with him on Motorcycle ,, then she has been discovered by the conductor who introduced her to people at opera concert and when she was singing , she fallen on stage and died .

2 the second story for her in another life , at Paris.

La Double Vie de Véronique (1991)

Two parallel stories about two identical women; one living in Poland, the other in France. They don't know each other, but their lives are nevertheless profoundly connected.

Wikipedia:

Weronika travels to Kraków by train looking out at the passing landscape through a small clear rubber ball. At her aunt's house, Weronika talks about her boyfriend, then meets a friend at a concert rehearsal. As the choir rehearses, Weronika, who is watching offstage, accompanies them in a beautiful high soprano voice. Afterwards, the musical director asks her to audition. Overjoyed, Weronika rushes home with the sheet music. On the way, she passes through Main Market Square, where a protest rally is in progress. One protester runs into her, causing her to drop her music folder. After retrieving the sheet music, Weronika notices a French tourist taking photos of the protestors—a young woman who looks exactly like her. Weronika smiles as she watches her double board the tourist bus that soon pulls away.
At the audition, Weronika's singing impresses the musical director and
  conductor, and she is later told that she won the audition. The next
  day, while on a trolley studying the score, Weronika notices her
  boyfriend Antek following on his motorbike. When they talk, she
  apologizes for not returning his calls, and Antek tells her he loves
  her. Later, while getting dressed for the concert, Weronika presses
  her face against a window and sees an old woman with shopping bags
  slowly making her way along the street. That night during the concert,
  while singing a solo part, Weronika collapses onstage and dies—her
  spirit passing over the audience.
Paris that day, a young French woman named Véronique (Irène Jacob), after making love with her former boyfriend, is overwhelmed with sadness, as if she were grieving. The next day, at the school where she teaches music, Véronique attends a marionette performance with her class. During the performance—a story about a ballet dancer who breaks her leg and then turns into a butterfly—Véronique watches the puppeteer controlling the marionettes. Back in her classroom, she leads her class in a musical piece by an eighteenth-century composer, Van den Budenmayer—the same piece performed by Weronika when she died. That night while driving home, she sees the puppeteer at a traffic light motioning to her not to light the wrong end of her cigarette. Later she is awakened by a phone call with no one speaking, but in the background she hears a choir singing the music of Van den Budenmayer.


yes , that's it .. thank you very much pori
